# Start server with help of Jetty runner

Tags: jetty

***What I have:***

Application which starts embedded jetty server in main method. When I need to move it on the server I should make a myApp.jar and launch it on the server.

***What I want:***
Not start embedded jetty server inside of application, but make myApp.war file and start it with help of Jetty runner

***What a problem:***
Before start embedded server I set WebsocketHandler to my server, and then ResourceHandler to the WebsocketHandler (see code below). *I have no idea how to pass those params with help of jetty runner command*.

***Question:***

May I use **java -jar jetty-runner.jar contexts/my.xml**?
If yes, how can I do that

***How I do it now:***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

WebSocketHandler handler = new WebSocketHandler() {
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
    factory.getPolicy().setMaxMessageSize(4533423);
    factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    factory.setCreator(creator);
  }
};
Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setHandler(handler);
ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resourceHandler .setDirectoriesListed(true);
resourceHandler .setResourceBase(WEB_CLIENT_PATH);
handler.setHandler(resourceHandler );
server.start();
server.join();
}
```

Comment: 34 reviews and any comment, despite the boundary period! Please describe why its so difficult ot answer my question?

Comment: Suggest you simplify your question.  Eliminate jetty-runner (its a 3rd party tool that not many folks use, so you automatically reduce the likelyhood of getting an answer).  You are juggling too many topics at once (embedded + jetty-runner + webappcontext from war + custom handlers).  Consider breaking down the question into sub questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to setup jetty, there is a way described in [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Using_Jetty_Runner):

`java -jar jetty-runner.jar --config my/jetty.xml my.war`

If no, what is `contexts/my.xml`?

Comment: I mean that I don't know how to pass WebSocketHandler and ResourceHandler in such way (with java -jar -jetty-runner.jar). Do I need to configure them in xml-file?

Comment: I guess if they are configurable using java, you could also configure them using jetty.xml.

Comment: yeah, actually the question is how to configure them with help of xml-file

Comment: Basically, take a look as syntax reference: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_syntax It's pretty powerful. For your handler it would be easier to create separate class.

Comment: Up to date Jetty XML Syntax doc is not in the wiki. See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/reference-section.html#jetty-xml-syntax